# Different Log File for different rails service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, puma

I've a rails service which I am starting up with Puma. I am using
`bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -p 3000`. However I've to start a new service on a different port let's say 3001. So, I've a different puma2.rb which I am starting with `bundle exec puma -C config/puma2.rb -p 3001`.
Both of these services have a common log file which is development.log. I want to seperate these log files say `development-3000.log & development-3001.log`.

I've tried

```
stdout_redirect "#{Dir.pwd}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{Dir.pwd}/log/puma.stderr.log"
```

for individual puma files but this logs only the requests. I want the log to be of **log_level : debug**. How can I achieve this?

Here is my puma config file:

```
app_path=File.expand_path('../', _ _FILE_ _)

tmp_dir= "#{app_path}/../tmp"

pidfile "#{tmp_dir}/pid"

state_path "#{tmp_dir}/state"

threads 8,32

workers 2

activate_control_app
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get separate logs would be to setup a separate rails environment. You could make a copy of the config/development.rb file and name it development2.rb, and then set the environment in the puma2.rb file to development2.

```
# puma2.rb
environment "development2"
```

That environment would write to development2.log